# How to bind dynamic checkbox value to Knockout observableArray on an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've posted my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lily30/s9yd0e7o/7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=s9yd0e7o) here, that has comments with it.

How can I convert/map the AllCustomers array into another array of Customer objects??

I need to push the checked checkboxes objects in to self.Customer(), {CustomerType,checked}

Then I would loop through list of Customer object Array and return an array of all checked Customers - self.CheckedCustomers

```js
function Customer(type, checked)
{
  var self = this;
  
  self.CustomerType = ko.observable(type);
  self.IsChecked = ko.observable(checked || false);
}

function VM()
{
  var self = this;
  
  //dynamically populated - this is for testing puposes
  self.AllCustomers = ko.observableArray([
    { 
      code: "001",
      name:'Customer 1'
    },
    { 
      code: "002",
      name:'Customer 2'
    },
    { 
      code: "003",
      name:'Customer 3'
    },
  ]);
  
 self.selectedCustomers = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.Customer = ko.observableArray([]);
  
//How can I convert the AllCustomers array into an array of Customer object??
//I need to push the checked object in to self.Customer(), {CustomerType,checked}

//uncomment below - just for testing looping through Customer objects
/*
self.Customer = ko.observableArray([  
    new Customer("001"),
    new Customer("002")
  ]);
*/
  
 // This array should return all customers that checked the box
self.CheckedCustomers = ko.computed(function()
{
    var selectedCustomers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Customer(), function (customer) {
        if(customer.IsChecked())
            selectedCustomers.push(customer);
    });
    return selectedCustomers;
});
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: AllCustomers -->
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data.code, checked:$parent.selectedCustomers" /> 
   
  <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
<br /> 
  <h4>selectedCustomers code</h4> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: selectedCustomers">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  </div>
  
  <h4>Checked boxes are??</h4> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: CheckedCustomers">
    <span data-bind="text: CustomerType"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: IsChecked"></span>
    <span>,</span>
  </div> 

<!-- Use this to loop through list of Customer object Array, uncomment below to test-->
<!-- 
  <!-- ko foreach: Customer --
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked" />
   
  <span data-bind="text: CustomerType"></span>
  <!-- /ko --
-->
```

Comment: First off, in the Customer function, you're hardcoding the IsChecked to false. You want to set that based on the checked parameter. That should give you a little bit of kickstart on what you're trying to acheive coz that's a major bug. Fix that, update fiddle, and post on further issues.

Comment: @BivoKasaju, I have updated my code. Am I heading the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert object with properties `code` and `name` to an object of properties `CustomerType` and `IsChecked`. I'm assuming you want `code` to be mapped to `CustomerType` when creating new `Customer` object.

Here's a working jsfiddle for more or less what you wanted.

https://jsfiddle.net/s9yd0e7o/10/

Added the following code:

```
self.selectedCustomers.subscribe(function() {
  self.Customer.removeAll();
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedCustomers(), function(item) {
      self.Customer.push(new Customer(item, true));
  });
});
```